# Laravel | Problema con bootstrap/cache/compiled.php

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer

Llevo un tiempo con un problema al ejecutar `composer update` en mi repositorio de producción. Solo en producción, en DEV y PRE no me pasa, todos tienen la misma configuración y al final tiran casi del mismo repositorio y comparten `composer.json`.

Estoy usando "laravel/framework": "5.2.*", con PHP 7.0

El problema que tengo es que al lanzar `composer update`, me genera este fichero: bootstrap/cache/compiled.php, pero solo en PROD; en ninguna de las otras versiones lo genera, ni en local. Con este fichero cargado la aplicación da un error 500 y reporta este fallo:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider, because the name is already in use in /var/www/vhosts/proyecto/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php on line 5267

Si borro a mano este fichero, la aplicación vuelve a funcionar, pero no debería de pasar esto. Además, las aplicaciones que intento instalar con composer, desde que tengo este fallo, no funcionan, las declaro en config/app.php y verifico que esté la carpeta en vendor y todo correcto, pero da otro 500 por lo que el motivo por el que no borra o genera bootstrap/cache/compiled.php hace que las instalaciones no terminen de ser correctas.

Por favor, podrían ayudarme, no se que más mirar o hacer.

Éste es mi composer:

```
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "^3.3",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
    "joshcam/mysqli-database-class": "dev-master",
    "opentok/opentok": "2.3.x",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "hisorange/browser-detect": "2.*",
    "ignited/laravel-omnipay": "2.*",
    "omnipay/omnipay": "*",
    "skecskes/calendar": "0.2.*",
    "webpatser/laravel-uuid": "^2.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.2",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",  
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
    "laracasts/flash": "^2.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "laravel/cashier": "~6.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.7.*",
    "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.7",
    "ovh/ovh": "^2.0",
    "docusign/esign-client": "^2.0",
    "sentry/sentry": "^1.6",
    "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^0.7.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"

},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
          "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
          "App\\": "app/"
        }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

Comment: empieza por quitar el `php artisan optimize` de los hooks post-install y post-update

Answer (score 0):

Intenta borrando la línea

"twbs/bootstrap": "^3.3" de tu composer.json

Verifica que el archivo package.json contenga una línea llamada "bootstrap-sass":"*Versión de bootstrap*"

Con todo esto, vuelve a ejecutar composer update

Comment: No me ha funcionado, sigue dando el mismo fallo.

Comment: Para la persona que respondió: No confundir el framework de CSS Boostrap con el proceso de *bootstrapping* de una aplicación, como en este caso.